# How to convert from serialized object to POJO

Tags: java, solr

In my Spring boot application I am trying to read an object from Solr search. During runtime the object name and its properties are returned as String. How can I convert the String to the corresponding POJO?

Object returned from Solr:

```
"Parameters(name=deviceType, value=D22, paramType=CONSTRUCTOR)"
```

POJO:

```
@UserDefinedType("parameters")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parameters implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8665215569152413443L;

    private String name;
    private String value;
    @JsonProperty("param_type")
    private String paramType;

}

@Data
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = ResultConstants.SOLR_CORE_NAME)
public class SolrRecord implements Serializable, Cloneable {

     @Field
     @Indexed(name = PARAMS, type = "text_general")
     private List<Parameters> params;
}
}
```

Is there a simple way to recreate the object from its string representation?

Actual result:

```
"Parameters(name=deviceType, value=D22, paramType=CONSTRUCTOR)"
```

Expected:
Parameters object

```
Parameters(name=deviceType, value=D22, paramType=CONSTRUCTOR)
```

Comment: may be https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-solr

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the object. Replace yourString below with your serialized object string. If the serialized object is actually a byte[], pass it without calling getBytes().

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( yourString.getBytes() );
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (is); 
// deserialization
Parameters object = (Parameters)in.readObject();
```